# How to call google vision legacy models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, io, google-vision

I want to use the legacy `text_detection` and `document_text_detection` model. (refer: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/service-announcements)
Im trying it this way using `features`:

```
import io
from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()


with io.open("/mnt/d/snap.png", 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)


response = vision_client.document_text_detection(image=image)
# print(response) --> uses stable models, works fine



feature = vision.Feature(model="builtin/legacy")

response = vision_client.document_text_detection(image=image, features=feature)
# print(response) --> throws error show below
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: dict() got multiple values for keyword argument 'features'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the call to `vision.Feature()` return? Is the type of `feature` a string? A list? Is it the type you expect to both receive from `vision.Feature()` and the one you want/need to send to `document_text_detection`?

Comment: it returns `model: "builtin/latest"`  the type of this is `<class 'google.cloud.vision_v1.types.image_annotator.AnnotateImageResponse'>`

Comment: We're facing same issue, did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import io from google.cloud import vision

vision_client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open("/mnt/d/snap.png", 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

#image = vision.Image(content=content)

response = vision_client.annotate_image({'image': {'content': content},'features': [{'type_': vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION,'model': "builtin/legacy"}]})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].